# VS2013 create new class from template

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Hi is this possible to create some template for Visual studio, that when I create new class it will contains some description in header ?

Comment: You could edit the current classtemplate, or just create a new one. So yes, you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Visual Studio 2012 you could do something like this:

1. Find the files

   C:\\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033

   The file you want is in an appropriately named folder. If you open the `Class` folder you will find the following 2 files:

   Class.cs

   Class.vstemplate
2. Backup the original files
3. Change the Class.cs template file
4. Save your changes
5. Tell Visual Studio about the changes

Your new changes will not be loaded unless you explicitly tell Visual Studio to reload all templates.

Close `Visual Studio` (or the change swill not show until next time you run it)
Open a command prompt (you should run this as Administrator if you are not an admin of the machine).
Change to the IDE folder a few levels above the template folder (e.g. to C:\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE)
Run the following command:

```
devenv.exe /installvstemplates
```